# How do I run build Release from the command line in Eclipse / Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

Is there a way to run a Export Release build from the command line in Flash Builder (Eclipse)?

**More Context**
Flash Builder has debug, run and build release commands or configurations (not sure what they're called). I want to put Flash Builder on the server and invoke the build release configuration from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Flash Builder on the server. You can do it with the Flex SDK, Java and Apache ANT installed on the server. If it is a Windows server you can set it up to run like this:

Create an ANT script to update from the repository, then build the Flash app.

Create a .bat file to run the ANT build (literally just a text file 'build.bat' in the folder with the build.xml that just says 'ant' in it).

Set up a scheduled task to run the build.bat at whatever interval you desire, or, if you have SVN on the same server you can set up a post commit hook to run that scheduled task so when a person commits to the repo, the build script will run and the new version can be viewed on the dev server.

I have an ANT script that also will email all devs if the build fails to let everyone know who broke the build, so they can take care of it. If you message me back I would be happy to post a zip for you with my ANT script files you can use an example.

EDIT: I've posted the files to GitHub in case anyone else needs them. https://github.com/royaldigit/ant-flash-build